# How to make OAuth2 work for Azure Active Directory with multi-factor authentication on .net?

Tags: .net, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

We are using [OAuth 2.0 auth code grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code) on Azure Active Directory to authenticate the users in our web application.

This has worked without problems, but now the AD maintenance wants to deploy a multi-factor authentication. Our current OAuth implementation is not in line with that.

Here is our code:

```
public static ActionResult LogOn()
{
    string authorizationUrl = string.Format(
        "https://login.windows.net/{0}/oauth2/authorize?api-version=1.0&response_type=code&response_mode=query&client_id={1}&scope={2}&redirect_uri={3}",
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(azureActiveDirectoryTenant),
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(azureActiveDirectoryClientId),
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/"),
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(azureActiveDirectoryCodeRedirectURL) // refers to Code() below
    );

    return new RedirectResult(authorizationUrl, false);
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Code(string code = null, string state = "", string error = null, string error_description = null)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
        {
            return LogOn();
        }
        AuthenticationContext ctx = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + azureActiveDirectoryTenant);
        ClientCredential clcred = new ClientCredential(azureActiveDirectoryClientId, azureActiveDirectoryClientKey);
        try
        {
            var ar = await ctx.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, new Uri(azureActiveDirectoryCodeRedirectURL), clcred, "https://graph.windows.net");
            string email = ar.UserInfo.DisplayableId;

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + ar.AccessToken);

                Stream data = client.OpenRead(new Uri("https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version=1.6"));
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
                Dictionary<string, dynamic> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(reader.ReadToEnd());
                data.Close();
                reader.Close();

                ... act on values and redirect...
            }
        }
        catch (AdalServiceException ex)
        {
            // We come here!
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = String.Format("Exception: ErrorCode: {0}, StatusCode: {1}, Message: {2}.", ex.ErrorCode, ex.StatusCode, ex.Message);
            ...
        }
    }
    return View("OAuthError");
}
```

And the error message:

```
ErrorCode: interaction_required, StatusCode: 400, Message: AADSTS50076: Due
to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a
new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000002-0000-
c000-0000000000000'.
```

[This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/conditional-access-dev-guide) is discussing conditional access on AAD and mentions 'claims' as a solution.

How does one incorporate claims to the code above to make it work?

Comment: You can try putting `amr_values=mfa` on the redirect URI to force MFA.

Comment: @juunas Thanks! I used `amr_values=ngcmfa` as advised [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt784627.aspx), and it seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oapx/0fc398ca-88d0-4118-ae60-c3033e396e60

You can add `amr_values=ngcmfa` to the authorization URL to force MFA.

You can also add `amr_values=mfa` to require that the user has gone through MFA, though it may have happened a while ago.

You should also then check that the token does contain "mfa" in the amr claim. (since the user could just remove the parameter)

Comment: Does not work for oauth2/v2.0/authorize. Parameter seems to be not supported. Any ideas how to do it in v2.0 j