# Azure Active Directory multi-factor check for authorization

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

We have requirements to enable MFA to check specific business flows. It means that a user can log in without MFA and do some stuff, but some flows will require MFA verification.

For example, a user can create a policy, but he cannot edit, delete policies without MFA.

We use Azure Active Directory and OpenID Connect for authentication/authorization.

I have checked if there are any options in Graph API for such things, but haven't found anything like this.

Could you please recommend or advice about possible options to implement such requirements?

Comment: My answer here might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/51824130/1658906. You can require MFA with that. Then you can check the token that it contains e.g. `"amr":["pwd", "mfa"]`

Comment: @JoeCai, thank you for your help. We can close this topic, your proposal looks the best what I could find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As junnas said, add `amr_values=ngcmfa` to the authorization URL to [force MFA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51785256/how-to-make-oauth2-work-for-azure-active-directory-with-multi-factor-authenticat/51824130#51824130) and then decoded the token which will contain `"amr": ["pwd","mfa"]`

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=https://localhost:123
&response_mode=fragment
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
&nonce=7362CAEA-9CA5-4B43-9BA3-34D7C303EBA7
&amr_values=ngcmfa
```